# Compile Latex files on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, latex, pdflatex, tex-live

I want to compile a Latex file from my android App to produce a pdf file.

Regarding this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87520/how-to-install-tex-on-android-phones, I have installed a portable version of [texlive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/). Then I have tried to copy it to the android device, but I got an error  "failed to copy '/usr/local/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/adhocfilelist' Function not implemented". 
I searched for the error but I didn't figure out the solution.

The other problem is that one should install [TeX Live for Android](https://code.google.com/p/texlive-for-android/) which support only arm architecture but I want to use x86 as well.

I have also tried to compile the texlive with NDK but it failed. I don't know how to configure it exactly!

Can anyone help me with these problems or suggest any other solutions.